# How to write integration tests to test Stripe integration in my node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, stripe-payments, integration-testing

How would you write integration tests to test Stripe integration in my node application?

Right now I've got a very simple node application that's using Stripe to accept credit/debit card payments.

I'm using the following Stripe library https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

e.g.

```
      const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 2000,
        currency: GBP,
        source: id,
      });

      if (!charge) throw new Error("charge unsuccessful");

      res.status(200).json({
        message: "charge posted successfully",
        charge,
      });
```

I can test the functionality manually.

How can I test this feature using integration and unit test?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of approaches you can take. The first would be to test the calls against your Stripe account's test mode data using your test API keys:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys

Stripe has many card numbers that you can use for test-mode tests, which are all defined here:

https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Note that you can safely make any calls to the API using your test keys and the behavior will (in almost every respect) mimic what would happen in live mode, except no real charges will be made:

https://stripe.com/docs/keys#test-live-modes

Apart from using your test API keys or mocking the stripe-node dependency entirely [using Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), another approach would be to use Stripe's official mock server:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock

The idea is that your ci/test environment would run the mock server and instead of hitting the real Stripe API with your test keys you would hit the mock server instead:

```
const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_xyz", {
  host: "localhost",
  protocol: "http",
  port: 12111,
});
```

If you initialize `stripe-node` like above, your calls will be made out to `http://localhost:12111` instead of `https://api.stripe.com`.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to do that in nodeJS? Using ava and sinon for mocking